# Обновление информации в приложении с сервера

Tags: android

К примеру при нажатии на `Button`, будет приходить в приложение обновлённый `String`, возможно ли это реализовать?

Имеется, к примеру, расписание занятий на неделю, которое хранится на сервере. Имеется `TextView`, в котором расписание занятий хранится в `strings.xml` и мне нужно, чтобы пользовтаель, раз в неделю, обновлял этот `string.xml`, с измененным на сервере расписанием.

Comment: Попробуйте изложить свой вопрос так, чтобы другим тоже было понятно, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Имеется текст в string, я поменял его на компе, залил на сервер и чтобы в приложении можно было обновить string с внесенными изменениями

Comment: Храните его в базе или в sharedPreferences

Comment: У вас есть какая то информация на сервере и вы хотите синхронизировать ее с андроид-устройством? Уточнение пишите в сам вопрос, пользуясь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, а не в комментарии под ним.

Comment: Извиняюсь, с телефона не удобно править

Comment: Так все таки на сервере обновляется информация или пользователь на устройстве будет обновлять

Comment: Так если расписание пар. То на сервере и на устройстве. Я заливаю измененный string на сервер, с новым расписанием, а пользователь обновляет

Comment: Вопрос был возможно ли, ответ да, возможно! Но если под string.xml вы имеете ввиду файл ресурсов, то у вас не получится его изменить, так как файлы ресурсов не изменяемы программно. Отсюда, вам прийдется переделать на хранение срок в отдельном файле string.xml, который не будет относится к ресурсам и вы сами будете его парсить и перезаписывать, либо же как написал @АндройдАндройд,  "Храните его в базе или в sharedPreferences"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку реализация в коде будет выглядеть достаточно громоздко, опишу общий алгоритм.

Во первых, ресурсы, хранящиеся в `strings.xml` нельзя изменять или подменять в процессе работы программы - это статические данные и они для вашей задачи не подходят.

Вам требуется организовать хранение динамических данных с сохранением состояния при закрытии. Для этого данные должны быть сохранены на внешнем носителе. Можно использовать запись в файл (как вариант - в .xml файл), запись в `SharedPreferences` или в базу данных. Для лучшего понимания рекомендуется прочитать [этот материал официального руководства](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)  по разработке под Android (кстати, любезно переведенное *Google* на русский язык).

Если требуется хранить расписание только на одну неделю и не требуется запоминать какие то заметки, задания и проч. дополнительную информацию к занятиям, то сохранение во внешний XML-файл будет предпочтительным решением. Для более сложной функциональности потребуется база данных.

Перед началом работы над приложением вам надо определиться с тем, в каком виде сервер будет отдавать данные. Для варианта с XML наиболее логично, чтобы сервер сразу же отдавал готовый XML с расписанием, для БД можно использовать JSON.

Теперь нам надо написать несколько классов для работы с нашими данными.

1. Класс работы с сетью, который получит от сервера нужные данные - XML или JSON с расписанием. Так же этот класс может включать метод преобразования полученных данных в формат хранения на устройстве (для БД эту задачу предпочтительней перенести в класс работы с БД)). Для XML требуется просто сохранение полученного файла на диск, для JSON - парсинг и внесение данных в БД.
2. Класс, извлекающий полученные данные из внешнего хранилища и преобразующий их в вид, удобный для программной обработки, например, в двумерный массив значений типа `String`. В строках будут содержаться занятия на текущий день, в столбцах - дни недели. Потребуется реализовать метод, который будет отдавать этот массив по запросу.
   Для XML это будет парсер из XML. Имеется возможность работать с DOM-, либо SAX-моделью.
   Окончательный выбор я оставлю за вами, но думаю, что для вашего случая лучше подойдет SAX. Android имеет стандартный класс для парсинга XML-документов в SAX формате - `XmlPullParser`. Небольшой [пример работы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/xmlpullparser.php) с этим парсером.
   Учтите, что в вашем случае сам документ нужно получать из внешнего хранилища, а не внутренних файлов ресурсов.
   Для БД это будет класс работы с базой данных `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Класс будет получать курсор из БД с запрошенными данными. Необходимо реализовать метод, который отдаст эти данные по требованию. Можно работать как напрямую с курсором (если вывод осуществляется через адаптер) или предварительно преобразовать их в удобный для программной обработки формат. Так же класс будет реализовать все другие необходимые вам методы работы с БД (запись, удаление, изменение, выборка других данных и тд). [Небольшой пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php) по работе с БД.
3. Далее, в активити вам нужно реализовать метод, который будет запрашивать подготовленные данные из класса пункта2 и размещать эти данные на разметке (выводить на экран).

Алгоритм работы всего этого добра следующий:

1. При старте приложение отображает данные через метод пункта3, если они были получены ранее или не отображает ничего, если это первый запуск и ждет нажатия на кнопку.
2. При нажатии на кнопку запускается класс пункта1, получающий с сервера текущее расписание и помещающий его во внешнее хранилище.
3. По завершению работы пункта2 этого алгоритма (данные получены от сервера и преобразованы) вызывается метод пункта3 описания классов (вывод на экран) и расписание отображается на экране.

Вся логика пунктов 2 и 3 находится в методе обработке клика кнопки.